# How to create a Query to select Employees NOT IN a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table for Employees in SQL SERver 2008 who are on vacation:

```
ID   Name  VacationStart   VacationEnd
---------------------------------------
01   A     05/12/17      05/14/17
01   A     05/18/17      05/22/17
02   B     04/28/17      05/02/17
02   B     05/19/17      05/21/17
03   C     04/16/17      04/18/17
```

I like to select all employees at the workplace

between '05/13/17' and '05/20/17' (date range: 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), then

the output will be:
    C
between '04/19/17' and '05/02/17'
the output will be:
    A and
    C
How do I create such a query?
In other words:
How to create a Query to select Employees NOT IN a date range?

Is there a way to create this query to compare a date range that is not present in a table without using Tally or Dates table?

PS: I don't use Tally or Dates table.

Thanks.

Comment: Columns VacationStart and VacationEnd's data type? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use NOT BETWEEN function

Comment: A calendar help table, storing all possible dates, could be handy.

Comment: Columns VacationStart and VacationEnd's data type are Date. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this requires first finding all the employees on vacation during the time frame, and then getting the list of employees not in that list.

```
select distinct Name from Employees
where Name NOT IN 
 (select Name from Employees
  where VacationStart <= '05/20/17'
     AND VacationEnd >= '05/13/17') IsOnVacation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good example where PostgreSQL date range fields and overlap operator would come in quite handy. :D

https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/73/Range-types-pgopen-2012.pdf

Otherwise, you're in for some really interesting SQL acrobatics.